# how to make the previous and next buttons invisible for asp.net ajax slideshow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Following this sample of slideshow asp.net ajax:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/SlideShow/SlideShow.aspx

with this code snippet:

```
<ajaxToolkit:SlideShowExtender ID="SlideShowExtender1" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="Image1" 
    SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides" 
    AutoPlay="true" 
    ImageTitleLabelID="imageTitle"
    ImageDescriptionLabelID="imageDescription"
    NextButtonID="nextButton" 
    PlayButtonText="Play" 
    StopButtonText="Stop" 
    PreviousButtonID="prevButton" 
    PlayButtonID="playButton" 
    Loop="true" />
```

If GetSlides() contains no image, how can I make the buttons Next and previous invisible? I think it is not user friendly to make them visible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to display/hide the buttons:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            //get slideshow behavior element
            var slide = $find('SSBehaviorID');
            //invoke web service method to get slides - call HideButtons method on success of web service method
            Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke(slide._slideShowServicePath, slide._slideShowServiceMethod, false, slide.params, HideButtons, null, null);
        }

        function HideButtons(result, eventArgs) {
            //get slideshow behavior element
            var slide = $find('SSBehaviorID');
            //if there are slides
            if (slide._slides) {
                if (slide._slides.length > 0) {
                    //don't hide buttons if there are slides
                }
                else {
                    //no images - hide buttons
                    $get("btnPlay").style.display = 'none';
                    $get("btnNext").style.display = 'none;';
                    $get("btnPrevious").style.display = 'none;';
                }
            }
            else {
                //hide buttons
                $get("btnPlay").style.display = 'none';
                $get("btnNext").style.display = 'none';
                $get("btnPrev").style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Make sure to set the ClientIDMode to static for the buttons so you can access them via script:

```
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrev" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server" Text="Previous" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnPlay" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnNext" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Next" />
```

This should give you the general idea. You can tweak the HideButtons routine as you need.

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of work on this on a blog post.

http://memmove.blogspot.com/2011/05/create-paging-button-for-each-slide-in.html

It isn't exactly the same, but may be helpful. Also, it deals a bit with the internals.

Answer (score 0):

In this example we are using Ajax SlideShow Extender which is usually used image Control for slide show.

```
 Public Function GetSlides() As AjaxControlToolkit.Slide()
        Dim MySlides(4) As AjaxControlToolkit.Slide
        MySlides(0) = New AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("photos/Tulips.jpg", "Tulips Pic", "Tulips")
        MySlides(1) = New AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("photos/Penguins.jpg", "penguins", "Penguins")
        MySlides(2) = New AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("photos/Lighthouse.jpg", "lighthouse", "light house")
        MySlides(3) = New AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("photos/Koala.jpg", "animal", "Strange Animal")
        MySlides(4) = New AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("photos/Jellyfish.jpg", "fish", "Jelly fisht")

        Return MySlides

    End Function
```